# What does c/o stand for in a postal address?

Tags: meaning

Sometimes when for some reason you have to give friends an address to receive mails, you write something like:

> Joe Black c/o John Doe
>   xxx ZZZ street
>   town... etc

What does *c/o* mean in this address?

Comment: [care fo](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/c/o?q=c%2Fo)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=c/o+meaning

Comment: I admit that the question is off topic. The reason that prevented me to find the answer by myself was the misspelling

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**c/o** here stands for **care of**.  The letter is to be delivered and entrusted to the care of John Doe, who will be responsible for seeing that it gets to Joe Black.

[**care of** on Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/care_of)

Wiktionary also suggests **c/-** is common in Australia and New Zealand.

Comment: I misspelled c/o into co. I actually had c/o in mind, thanks

Answer (score 3):

In the UK, "**Co.**" would normally stand for "**Company**", at the end of a company name.

Despite the non-capitalisation of "co." in the title, my first thought was "**Joe Black Company**". This is often used (or used to be) in a format such as "**Joe Black Co. Ltd.**" meaning "**Joe Black Company Limited**".

The most common abbreviation in the UK for "**care of**" is "**c/o**", so we would have written

> Joe Black **c/o** John Doe

In fact, I note that the [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/care_of) link given by @NateEldredge gives "**c/o**" as the first abbreviation listed, and does not even list "**co**".

Comment: I misspelled c/o into co. I actually had c/o in mind, thanks